# Setting a username and password for shared folders - windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

how do I set a password for my shared folders if my laptop/user account doesn't have a password?

All the guides online say the shared folder password will be "your password that you use to login when you restart your computer" but I don't have a password for that.

Comment: So why don´t you just setup login credentials for your computer? That would take care of your problem and make your system that much safer.

Comment: I would rather not put login credentials on my laptop for personal reason though I am aware of the security benefits. I would just like to know how to set a password for the shared folder.

Comment: All the guides online are correct. What you want to do is not possible.

Comment: You can set a password,. then set auto-login; which will feel like the same thing. You can then simply follow any of the guides.

Comment: @Tetsujin This sounds like the best trade off. Where's the setting for for auto-login?

Comment: @DavidPostill ah okay. think it's a little stupid for windows not to do this but oh well.

Comment: You need to set your account password before doing this, of course, just in the standard Users panel, then... Click Start, type `netplwiz`, hit Enter. Uncheck 'users must enter a PW' & select a login user & hit Apply. It will ask you to confirm PW details; next boot should auto-login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this workaround by using BAT files:

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/password-protect-folder-windows-10

Comment: Why does the body of your answer not contain the relevant information from your link?  Why am I forced as a reader to view content on a website other than Superuser?